# datatable th value should come in dropdown as per attached image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my fiddle, I need my th value/text to show in my drop down just like a placeholder.

Here is the image which I want to achieve through my Jquery code.

jsfiddle.net/gkm0L680/1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have update your fiddle you can check.

> you just get title text and added into default option

```
var title = $($("#filters").find("th")[column.index()]).text();
var select = $('<select><option value="">'+title+'</option></select>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` does have a function which returns the current header, you could simple read the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) from that node.

```
$('<select><option value="">' + this.header().textContent + '</option></select>')
```

[Demo (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/d0eseLcg/1/)